# how do we get the image height (not natural height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, height

if an image populates dynamically inside a div having **min-height** how do we get the height of the image (not **natural height**)

```
<div class="card_bg">
  <img class="card_img" src="images/card_bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**image dimensions: 394 * 222 pixels (Natural: 720 * 405 pixels)**

Now, how to get `222` as height using **javascript or jquery**.

Comment: @Eddie that question show the opposite, to get 222 you just use `$('.card_img').height()`

Comment: I think the best is if you post a working code snippet reproducing the issue, and we go from there. Until then I decided to delete my answer, as we actually doesn't really know what goes wrong.

Comment: I think by now you must realize that natural and height doesn't mean anything. Do you want the actual dimensions of the image file, the size it takes up in the dom or something else?

Answer (score 2):

According to Jquery documentation get the height and width by using `.height()` and `.width()`

Example:

```js
let height = $('#test').height();
let width = $('#test').width();
alert(height +" "+ width);
```

```css
#test{
  height:150px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: the image comes dynamically and i am not setting the height and width of the img tag in css, all i have is a parent div with min-height and the img inside it.

Comment: You asked 'how to get the height'. So what's the problem? You want to set the height? I don't think I understand you...

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual height of that image, you should use this code in javascript.

```
 var height = document.getElementsByClassName("card_img")[0].height;
```

it will only give you that particular image height.